# Is it possible to place an org in it's own process

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

So we have 2 Orgs in our dev CRM environment. Both orgs are using the same worker process (w3wp.exe). So whenever one developer hits a breakpoint in a plugin it locks the process and both orgs stop responding.

My question is.. is it possible to put each org in its own process?

Comment: Could you not make the breakpoint conditional on the organisation name? Can you post an example break point you are hitting?

Comment: @glosrob, thanks for the response. It doesn't matter how or when the breakpoint is hit, just that when it does, it stops w3wp.exe, which in turn stops all orgs from responding. An example would be a breakpoint anywhere in a plugin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. However, the newest SDK has a new feature in the Plugin Tool that lets you debug plugins locally. Basically, you enable "Profiling" for your plugin through the tool, then go do the action in CRM that would normally fire your plugin. You'll get a pop-up exception, at which point you "Download Log." It is a big base-64 encoded text file. Then, you go back into Plugin Registration tool and click the Debug button, supply your download log file, attach Visual Studio to the Plugin Tool, and then click Start. The Plugin Tool uses the log file to completely recreate the Context that would normally be passed into your plugin, and since Visual Studio is attached to the Plugin Tool, your breakpoints are hit like normal.

Comment: You have a real knack for finding supported ways of doing things where others (read: me) make hacks. Thanks for the info, Josh!