# Plugin debugging - user always needs to be logged on?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, remote-debugging

I have just set up the plugin remote debugger on my CRM server as a service and I can now connect to it and debug plugins with no problem.

My question is does the user always need to be logged onto the server in order for the service to be running and working? I set it up so that it runs as LocalSystem but when the user isn't logged in and I try to debug anything it says I cannot connect to it.

So does this mean I have to keep the user on always or is there some configuration that I've missed?

Comment: Do you mean the "Visual Studio remote debugger"?

Comment: The service is actually installed and started?

Comment: Yeah its in the list as started and it is currently set up to log in as local system account

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be logged in to run the remote debugger- it is designed to be set up for short term debugging and turned off after you are finished debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Using the PluginTool for local debugging on your workstation is another option:

[Is it possible to place an org in it's own process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401537/is-it-possible-to-place-an-org-in-its-own-process/8406398#8406398)